# Black screen on boot on a Dell Vostro 3555

Tags: 11.10, boot

Loaded Ubuntu 11.10 (64 bit) onto brand new Vostro 3555 (AMD A6) and won't boot (black screen).

Tried nomodeset in Grub.. still nothing. At a loss.

Comment: Found the fix. You get yourself to the boot prompt.. login.. then 'sudo apt-get install fglrx'. Once you're running then enable your 'proprietary software'.. in this case the AMD/ATI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Comment converted to an answer*

Found the fix. You get yourself to the boot prompt and then log in to your system. Then install fglrx using the command: `sudo apt-get install fglrx`.

After that, log into your graphical interface and then enable your 'proprietary software'. In this case, it is the AMD / ATI.